# How to create list of ThemeColor in Theme3D QML type?

Tags: qt, qml, qt6, scatter3d, qtdatavisualization

Created custom [`Theme3D`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtdatavisualization-theme3d.html) for `Scatter3D` component ([**QtDataVisualization**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtdatavisualization-index.html) module) like this:

```
Theme3D {
    id: themeDark
    type: Theme3D.ThemeIsabelle
    font.pointSize: 20
    baseColors: [
        "red",
        "green", 
        "blue"
    ]
}
```

However got error when running application:

`Color is invalid, use ThemeColor`

Qt documentation mentions:

> [`baseColors : list<ThemeColor>`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtdatavisualization-theme3d.html#baseColors-prop): The list of base colors to be used for all the objects in the graph, series by series. If there are more series than colors, color list wraps and starts again with the first color in the list.

and no example how to initialize the list properly. How to change **baseColors** property?

Answer (score 0):

Solved like this:

```
    baseColors: [
        ThemeColor { color: "red" }, 
        ThemeColor { color: "green" },
        ThemeColor { color: "blue" }
    ]
```

However got another problem:

1. st series is black
2. nd - is red
3. rd - is green

Created [QTBUG-101033](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-101033) bug report for Qt to solve this.